# using the bintray-plugin and license-gradle-plugin together

Tags: gradle, groovy, bintray

I am following the [gradle-bintray guide](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#step-6-define-artifacts-to-be-uploaded-to-bintray) and the config works. The problem occurs, when I also activate the the [license-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin).

Without the license-plugin the following config works (the pom file is created correctly):

```
// Create the pom configuration:
def pomConfig = {
    licenses {
        license {
            name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
            url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
            distribution "repo"
        }
    }
```

When I also activate the license plugin, I need to configure it like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"
license {
    header rootProject.file('LICENSE_HEADER')
    ext.year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
    ...
}
```

Now the bintray plugin creates an invalid pom file. The `license` node is missing. I think, the problem is that the configuration of the license plugin is now used in the pom config object definition:

```
// Create the pom configuration:
def pomConfig = {
    licenses {
        license { # THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE!
            name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: see also: https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/183

Answer (score 0):

The workround proposed in the [hierynomus license-gradle-plugin #138](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin/issues/138#issuecomment-307143421) works.

When you configure the bintray-plugin use `license`**([:])**

```
def pomConfig = {
  licenses {
    license([:]) { // right here, using license as function call
      name "The Apache Software License, Version 2.0"
      url "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt"
      distribution "repo"
    }
  }
}
```